# Remove required field value from devextreme form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devextreme

I work with asp.net mvc and devextreme
I have model with bool value and I will add form in the view

my problem is when I uncheck the checkbox I got a validation message the checkForImges field is required

I want to remove it and the red border

view code

```
@model ArchiveConfigManager.Models.QueryRetrieve
@using DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc
@(Html.DevExtreme().Form().ID("form")
.ShowValidationSummary(false).ShowRequiredMark(false).
ShowOptionalMark(false).
ShowColonAfterLabel(false)
.ColCount(1)
.Items(items =>
{
    items.AddGroup()
    .Items(groupItems =>
    {      
      groupItems.AddSimple().DataField("CheckForImages").
      IsRequired(false).Label(l => l.Visible(false)).
      Editor(e => e.CheckBox().Text("Check For Images"))
      ;})
   ;})
      .FormData(Model)
      )
```

model code

```
 public class QueryRetrieve
    {
        public bool CheckForImages { set; get; }
}
```

[the result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqzxn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASP.NET framework considers any non-nullable properties as required. So, to avoid the issue you can mark your CheckForImages property as nullable:

```
public class QueryRetrieve
    {
        public bool? CheckForImages { set; get; }
     }
```